# Focus window of my application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a WPF application with two xaml windows from two different dlls. Both Dlls load at the same time and display their windows which works fine. There is also another window of a third party software.

Please note that all windows are borderless (windowstyle = none).

My problem is that I want the focus to remain with one of the two xaml windows. As soon as the focus goes to the third party software window, I want any one of the xaml window to regain it. How can I achieve this? Maybe in OnDeactivate event?

```
    public void OnMainGUIDEactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activate();
    }
```

// Tried to add application deactivate

```
    public MyFirstView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.Deactivated += AppDeactivated;

    }

    void AppDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Application deactivated
        Activate();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried OnDeactivate event which works fine if I have one xaml but I want to additionally add a condition that activate() should fire only if my second xaml is not active

Answer (score 1):

The event you're after is : `Application.Current.Deactivated`

you can then call it to reactivate, so you can then call either of your forms with `whatever.Activate()` and it will bring it back

Comment: In one of the xaml constructor I did (Code added in the question) but my xaml does not show?

Answer (score 0):

There's a MVVM / Blend approach:

Declare this on your window:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"                
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then call the focus method on Deactivated event of your window

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Deactivated" >
        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Focus" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=mywindow}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: How will I check that the second xaml is not activated?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by a work around.

On both xamls I used Topmost="True"